# Trigger intercom-composer-send-button

Tags: javascript, jquery, intercom

I'm using intercom, and I want write an new message in the chat-window and do an submit. Writing the message works with `Intercom('showNewMessage','some message')`, but when  I try a

```
$('button.intercom-composer-send-button').trigger('click');
```

there is no effect. Some idea to send the message without a user action is needed?

Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

You can do the submit after the messenger is loaded this way:

```
var intercomIframe = $( "iframe[name='intercom-messenger-frame']" ).contents();
    intercomIframe.find( ".intercom-composer-send-button" ).trigger( 'click' );
```